# Custom ListView with Spinner

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemselectedlistener

==== Updated ====

There was a typo in the code block, so made you guys confused. What I want to do is to get the id of list item of list view, which holds the spinner that I'm clicking right now.

==== Updated ====

I'm implementing a custom list view which has spinner and text box for each list item. And I want to save selected value of spinner using `onItemSelected()` in list item of list view, but I don't have any idea to find a list item. How can I get this, can anyone help this?

Below is my codes in list view adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;

    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.view1 = (Spinner) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
        viewHolder.view2 = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.view2);

        viewHolder.view1.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.view2.setFocusable(false);

        viewHolder.view1.setAdapter(view1Adapter);
        viewHolder.view1.setPrompt("Select");
        viewHolder.view1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedId = spinnerItemList.get(position).id;
                // todo : need to find a way to get list item of list view, which has this spinner.
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        listItemView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    CustomListItem item = listViewItemList.get(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = listItemView.getTag();
    viewHolder.view1.setSelection(item.view1Value);
    viewHolder.view2.setText(String.valueOf(item.view2Value));

    return listItemView;
}
```

Comment: can you add full code of adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work..

```
String selectedId = spinnerItemList.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find selected item by using below snippet.

```
viewHolder.view1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {elo

    //here if you use single Field then belo line is true to get id.

            String selectedId = spinnerItemList.get(position);

    //if you using pojoclass for data set & get then you need to do like below.

            String selectedId = spinnerItemList.get(position).getId();
    // todo : need to find a way to get list item index.


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: oops, there was a typo in code block, I can get the id of selected item of spinner. What I want to do is to get the id of list item of list view, which holds spinner that I'm clicking now.